# cucumber watir firefox not shutting down after test

Tags: firefox, cucumber, bdd, watir

I've just started using cucumber and watir for some site testing, and it all work fine, but firefox doesn't shut down after the tests. I get this error:

```
!!! error running onStopped callback: TypeError: callback is not a function
*** LOG addons.xpi: shutdown
!!! error running onStopped callback: TypeError: callback is not a function
*** LOG addons.xpi: shutdown
!!! error running onStopped callback: TypeError: callback is not a function
*** LOG addons.xpi: shutdown
```

Any ideas, anyone?

Sorry - forgot the sample code!

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

Before do
  $browser = Watir::Browser.new
end

After do
  $browser.close
end

Given ... (etc. - all the step defs here)
```

Comment: Please share the code that causes the error.

Comment: Oops - sorry, schoolboy error :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using global variable `$browser` in `Before` and `After` blocks? Try using instance variable `@browser` instead. (Make sure to change all occurrences of `$browser` with `@browser`.)